# why am i getting malloc error?

Tags: linux, timer, malloc

i'm trying to use timer_create() function, but i got the net error:

```
*** glibc detected *** /media/.../Menu: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0805d0f8 ***
```

my call to the function is as follow:

```
if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stSigEvent, &(pStruct->tTimer)) != -1)
```

and the definitions as follow:

```
timer_t tTimer; /* in the struct pStruct */
struct sigevent stSigEvent;
```

for now i don't have call for free in my program.

i don't have an option to run valgrind.
Thanks.

Comment: Please explain why you cannot use `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

You would get this error

> *** glibc detected *** /media/.../Menu: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0805d0f8 ***

if you are trying to access a memory region not allocated by you or you must be overflowing you allocation, like allocate for 4 bytes and access 5 bytes.

To answer you problem , is srtuct pStruct a struct variable or a struct pointer
if it is a variable then you should change timer_create to this

> if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stSigEvent, **&(pStruct.tTimer)**) != -1)  // notice the method has been changed from '->' to  '.'

Comment: Hi #Santosh A, i know the reasons that may cause this error.
it isn't my case. i think so. The above line is the first try to access to &(pStruct->tTimer), nothing before.
second, it is pointer to struct.

Comment: Hi #Shtrudle, If it is pointer to struct, in that case have you allocated memory to the pointer before passing to timer_create

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have some [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) in your code *elsewhere* and *before* the actual code calling `timer_create`

You should compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and **use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)** ; I can't see any reason to avoid using `valgrind` if it is available on your system.

<sup>Notice that the latest [valgrind 3.9](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.news.html) can run on many platforms, not only x86 but also ARM etc...</sup>

Try also, with a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.or/) 4.9 (or even 4.8) compiler -or with a *recent* [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler-, its [address sanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/); that is, add `-fsanitize=address` to the compilation (and linking) flags.

Comment: Hi, i looked for memory corruption elsewhere and didn't find. without timer_create call it continues running. I don't realy know why can't i install valgrind, i tried. my linux doesn't connect to network. mayby that.

Comment: You didn't find your memory corruption, but it is still there! Finding them is hard. You really should take several hours to install tools like `valgrind` and/or a recent GCC.

Comment: when i add ‘-fsanitize=address’ i get the next error: cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fsanitize=address’

Comment: As I said, you need a *recent version* of GCC. Please install GCC 4.9.1 or newer (perhaps by compiling the GCC compiler from its source tarball).

Comment: I understand that, but i cannot connet it to the network. Anyway' thanks.

Comment: In the previous century, when tools like `valgrind` did not exist (or were too expensive), hunting memory leak bugs took me *weeks* of work. So spending a few hours to install `valgrind` is worth the time. At the very least, you could download the source code (of `valgrind-3.9` and perhaps `gcc-4.9`), put them on USB stick from another machine, and compile them on your isolated Linux.

Comment: where am I need to put the installation files?